# Destruction of string temporaries in thrown exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, destructor, temporary

Consider the following code:

```
std::string my_error_string = "Some error message";

// ...

throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Error: ") + my_error_string);
```

The string passed to runtime_error is a temporary returned by string's `operator+`.  Suppose this exception is handled something like:

```
catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

When is the temporary returned by string's `operator+` destroyed?  Does the language spec have anything to say about this?  Also, suppose runtime_error took a `const char*` argument and was thrown like this:

```
// Suppose runtime_error has the constructor runtime_error(const char* message)
throw std::runtime_error((std::string("Error: ") + my_error_string).c_str());
```

Now when is the temporary string returned by operator+ destroyed?  Would it be destroyed before the catch block tries to print it, and is this why runtime_error accepts a std::string and not a const char*?

Comment: Nitpick: `std::runtime_error("Error: " + my_error_string);` is fine because `my_error_string` is of type string. You don't have to explicitly call the `std::string` constructor on `"Error: "` and clutter your code.

Comment: I would prefer `std::string("Error: ").append(my_error_string)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a temporary object (12.2), the result of the `+` will be destroyed as the last step in the evaluation of the *full-expression* (1.9/9) that contains it. In this case the *full-expression* is the *throw-expression*.

A *throw-expression* constructs a temporary object (the *exception-object*) (15.1) (`std::runtime_error` in this case). All the temporaries in the *throw-expression* will be destroyed after the *exception-object* has been constructed. The exception is thrown only once the evaluation of the *throw-expression* has completed, as the destruction of temporaries is part of this evaluation they will be destroyed before the destruction of automatic variables constructed since the try block was entered (15.2) and before the handler is entered.

The post-condition on `runtime_error`'s constructor is that `what()` returns something that `strcmp` considers equal to what `c_str()` on the passed in argument returns. It is a theoretical possiblility that once the `std::string` passed as a constructor argument is destroyed, `runtime_error`'s `what()` could return something different, although it would be a questionable implementation and it would still have to be a null-terminated string of some sort, it couldn't return a pointer to a stale `c_str()` of a dead string.

Answer (score 8):

runtime_error is a class which contains a string. That string will be managed for you by the normal C++ construction and destruction mechanisms. If it contained a char *, then that would have to be explicitly managed, but you would still not have to do anything as a *user* of runtime_error.

Despite what you may read elsewhere on the internet, C++ is designed to almost always do "the reasonable thing" - you actually have to try fairly hard to break this reasonable behaviour, though of course it is not impossible to do so.

Comment: To answer the question of destruction: the temporary created will get destructed as soon as the `std::runtime_error` object exists (ie, its constructor terminated successfully). Of course, the object has a copy of it, so it does not matter ;)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the runtime_error exception class makes a copy of the string passed into the constructor. So when you're calling .what() on the exception object, you're not getting back the same exact string instance you passed in.

So to answer your question, the temporary you're asking about gets destroyed "at the semicolon" of the expression that contains it (this is true in both your first and second version of the question), but as I said, this isn't that interesting, because a copy of it was already made.